# Prove that at least one of null space or range is infinite-dimensional.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $T:V \rightarrow W$ be a linear transformation. If $V$ is infinite-dimensional, prove that at least one of the range or null space of $T$ is infinite-dimensional.

The question has an accompanying hint:

Assume $\mathrm{dim}N(T) = k$ and $\mathrm{dim}T(V) = r$. Let $e_1, \dots , e_k$ be a basis for $N(T)$ and $e_1, \dots , e_k, e_{k+1}, \dots, e_{k+n}$ be independent elements in $V$, where $n>r$. The elements $T(e_{k+1}), \dots , T(e_{k+n})$ are dependent since $n>r$. Use this fact to obtain a contradiction.

I have no idea how to proceed with this.

Comment: Do you know the rank-nullity theorem?

Comment: @TheoBendit isn't the rank-nullity theorem applicable only for the finite-dimensional case?

Comment: It is, but it applies here with a little creativity. I'm writing up an answer to demonstrate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a slicker way to approach this than the hint suggests, though it's much the same logic underneath.

Suppose $U$ is a subspace of $V$, and consider $S = T|_U : U \to W$. Note that $\operatorname{N}(S) \subseteq \operatorname{N}(T)$ and $S(U) = T(U) \subseteq T(V)$ (if you doubt this at all, you should prove it!).

Now, in particular, if $V$ is an infinite-dimensional vector space, then $V$ contains a finite-dimensional subspace $U$ of any dimension $n$. In particular consider
$$n = \operatorname{dim} \operatorname{N}(T) + \operatorname{dim} T(V) + 1,$$
assuming the nullspace and image are finite-dimensional. Then, defining $S$ as the restriction to $U$ as above, the rank-nullity theorem says
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{dim} U &= \operatorname{dim} \operatorname{N}(S) + \operatorname{dim} S(U) \\
&\le \operatorname{dim} \operatorname{N}(T) + \operatorname{dim} T(V) \\
&= n - 1 = \operatorname{dim} U - 1,
\end{align*}
a contradiction.

Comment: Perhaps you should have the dimension of $T(V)$ rather than $T(U)$ in your definition of $n$. Right now you define $U$ by demanding that its dimension is $n$, while the definition of $n$ also refers to $U$.

Comment: @Blazej Thanks, it was a typo. The definition was indeed impredicative.

Answer (score 0):

We have the first isomorphism theorem $\mathrm{im}(T)=\frac{V}{\mathrm{ker}(T)}$, so if the kernel is finite dimensional, then the image is not. This relies on the fact that quotient of an infinite-dimensional vector space by a finite-dimensional subspace is infinite-dimensional, which can easily be inferred directly from the definition of dimension of a vector space.

By the way, we still have rank-nullity theorem (which is really a trivial corollary of the first isomorphism theorem) in the form $\mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{ker}(T))+\mathrm{dim}(\mathrm{im}(T))=\mathrm{dim}(V)$. One just has to be careful when manipulating this expression, because $x+y=x+z$ does not imply $y=z$ when $x$ is infinite. In the exercise at hand this is not a problem.